# SSD is slower on PC

Tags: windows-10, ssd, performance

Yesterday I bought Samsung 850 Evo 250GB. It's now my boot drive and has Windows 10 pro installed on it.

I benchmarked the SSD with Crystal Disk benchmark. All the scores reported by crystal disk were closer to what other users reported ie sequential read write are above 500MB/S, however the **4kq32** score was

> Read: 150MB     Write: 140MB

This has me concerned because other users reported over 300MB/s for read and write.

Why my SSD is reporting such low numbers?

My PC specifications

- Intel i7 2670qm
- 8GB RAM
- 700GB secondary HDD
- HP pavilion dv6t 6c19tx

Comment: It could be your motherboard not support sata 3 or 6g.  Your speeds match SATA1 almost perfectly.

Comment: My motherboard has sata3

Comment: Did you try another SATA port as sometimes all the ports are not 6g.  I got a single SATA1 port for optical drives.  Check you have AHCI and SATA 3 turn on in the BIOS.

Comment: I installed the ssd in hdd place. Moved the hard-disk to dvd rom area

Comment: If my port was not sata 3, will i be able to score over 500MB/S on sequntial read write?

Comment: Check your driver versions, and make sure they are update-to-date.

Comment: You mean driver of the ssd? I didn't install the Samsung magician software because some users reported that the firmware update screwed their ssd and reduced the speeds by several foldes

Comment: SATA 1  150mb/s  SATA 2 300mb/s  sata 3  600mb/s.  Your drive should be around 500-550mb/s read and 300mb/s probably correct for write speeds.

Comment: Your motherboard has a SATA controller built in, and that is the driver you need to update.

Comment: The confusing part is I'm getting 500MB/S for sequential read write on crystal disk. Only 4kqd32 is reporting such low numbers. Besides which drivers did you Mr to update? I just installed Windows 10 updates after clean install. Also i havent installed Samsung magician software that comes in the box of the ssd

Comment: 4kqd32   The 4k is the block size, and that is ridiculously small amount of data to write and it takes longer.  Most of the time windows caches data till there are several MB of data to write.  You probably have an intel mobo so you need to go to intel.com and find the RST drivers.

Comment: Correct. I guess that's the problem. I have read the posts regarding people reporting slow speeds, a few of them resolved it when ahci drivers from Intel. I didn't install them and i think windows 10 installed those drivers itself. I'll install the latest drivers for ahci and report back

Comment: A 4k block is like paint a house with a crayon, 1M-8mb is like a power painting machine.

Comment: @cybernard I have posted full details here. Please  have a look
https://superuser.com/questions/1078193/ssd-is-very-slow-on-pc